# Probability densities and Absolute continuity

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I've not deep knowledge in measure theory/real analysis but just few concepts given me during this second year probability course. I'm trying by myself to understand more, but I don't want to dive in measure theory theorems, but just understanding basic ideas.

In this curse we didn't talk too much of condition for the existence of a density. So here is my questions:

- 1) Given a probability $P$ on the space $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$, it admits continuos density if it is absolutely continuos with respect with $n$- dimensional Lebesgue measure $m$, thus:$$P \ll m \implies \exists f : P(A) = \int_A f \ \mathrm{d}m$$
  I think that an equivalent way to say this is that if $P \ll m$ then exists the Radon-Nykodim derivative $\frac{dP}{dm}$.
  Are these sentences true? It's only a if or a iff?
- 2) Now I'm wondering if it's possible to translate the same concepts on the discrete case. Given a probability $P$ on the space $(\Omega,2^\Omega)$, with $\Omega$ discrete, it admits discrete density (mass density) it is absolutely continuos with respect with counting measure $H^0$, thus:$$P \ll H^0 \implies \exists f : P(A) = \int_A f \ \mathrm{d}H^0 = \sum_{x \in A} f(x)$$
  Equivalently, like before, we can talk about RN derivative.
  It's fine or not?

I repeat that I only know a little of measure theory and I only want to understand better when densities exist in a unified framework (discrete + continuous).

Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re 1., "if" is indeed "iff". Re 2., *every* measure on a discrete set $\Omega$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the counting measure since $H^0(A)\ne0$ for every $A\subseteq\Omega$, $A\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 2) This explains why we never bother about existence of mass functions. 1) So saying simply that densities and mass functions are Radon-Nykodim derivatives of probability measure it's sufficient, right? Thanks again